# How to fix formulas calculating with CTRL+ALT+F9, but not with F9

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet into which data gets inserted from an outside software before it is opened. It returns either the empty string ("") or the number as string.

There is some really strange behaviour from Excel now though. The Data Points get copied into another cell without a problem although the `0`s do not get inserted. Instead the cells just stay empty. The formula depending on that value just shows `#NV`.

The formulae seem to be correct as when one of the Origin cells is clicked and Enter is pressed, the depending values get calculated correctly.

Also "`F9`" doesn't do anything while `CTRL+ALT+F9` calculates the whole sheet correctly. To me this seems really strange as if Excel just "doesn't know" the values have changed.

So we have 2 indications that don't match.

1. Since `CTRL+ALT+F9` calculates all values it seems Excel just doesn't "know" it needs to calculate.
2. Since the values get copied it seems Excel does start doing something and stops for some reason.

I tried everything I can think of. Reformatting the cells, casting the input as an int before entering in into Excel and much more.

The formulae and result look like this. If `CTRL+ALT+F9` these are all numbers instead of just the copied values that are drawn from another cell.

It looks like this:

[image: Picture without formula]
[image: Picture with formula]

It's German Excel

Formula left:

```
IF(LENGTH(G6)=0;0;G6)
```

Formula right:

```
IF(F18>0;VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(G$2;" ";F18);Frequenzen!$A:$D;3;FALSCH);"")
```

Edit:
Autocalculate is turned on by the way. I also already tried putting `VALUE()` around everything since values are entered as strings. I don't really think formatting is a problem though as it calculates correctly when I force it to recalculate the whole sheet.

VBA is not an option as a solution since documents are saved on a server where it's not allowed.

Comment: GSD: I accepted your formatting improvements except for the grammar stuff. Behaviour/Behavior as well as formulae/formulas are both correct english. Or did I miss a rule we only use the American version here?

Answer (score 0):

From [Support Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f):

> Calculate all worksheets in all open workbooks.
>
> <kbd>F9</kbd>
>
> Calculate the active worksheet.
>
> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
>
> Calculate all worksheets in all open workbooks, regardless of whether
>   they have changed since the last calculation.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
>
> Check dependent formulas, and then calculate all cells in all open
>   workbooks, including cells not marked as needing to be calculated.
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

So based on the last part of what was added to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> "...regardless of whether they have changed since the last calculation" to me implies that for the previous two case calculations will only occur if a change has been flagged.

Comment: Not sure if it can be done or not, but you may need some VBA code that monitors worksheet change for when you do the paste and when there has been a change it forces the CTRL+ALT+F9 action to occur.

Comment: Yup while that's true and my first conclusion(don't know a solution though), the second behaviour is what puzzles me since it copies the values that are there but doesn't execute the same code when there is no value in the original cell. On pressing "Enter" in both cases the whole calculation tree does it's work though. So if that's the case I'd expect at least in cases when there is a value that the calculations are made.

Comment: VBA is not an option as those documents are saved on a server where makros are not allowed unfortunately.

Comment: Add that VBA not an option to your question in case I delete this answer in the future...also saves other from having to read this comment section to find that important information.

Comment: I get something similar happening with copy and paste with numbers sometimes.  They will get interpreted as text during the paste, but if I hit F2 to edit the cell, do nothing and hit enter they then get interpreted as numbers.  Unfortunately I do not have a solution.  Tends to happen on small data sets so I usually just wind up making the manual correction and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, in a simpler setting.  My workbook just fails to recognize that a value has changed in a cell on another sheet which the cell in question is dependent on.

There are no error messages.  Automatic recalc is on.  There is no error in the formulas because retyping the exact same formula into the cell as was already there forces the necessary recalculation.   Moreover, the problem occurs only when the workbook grows beyond a certain size (that certain size being about 6 mb on a machine with 32GB RAM).  The workbook records incoming orders, with each new order being a new page, and sums across the order sheets to get order totals, and does calculations on other sheets that track inventory.  All very simple.  Just adding, subtracting and multiplying.  If I hit ctrl-alt-f9, then all cells update to correct values.

My conclusion is Excel has a bug in its smart recalculation code.

Comment: You can report it to Microsoft and get their explanation.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30682965)